# Doctrine error - expected end of string, got "ORDER"

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Using Symfony 4 / Doctrine, I got an error with this query :

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->update()
        ->set('s.dateCreate', ':date_new')
            ->setParameter('date_new', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
        ->where('s.site = :site')
            ->setParameter('site', $site)
        ->orderBy('s.dateCreate', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

I got this error :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 81: Error: Expected end of string, got 'ORDER'
```

If I remove the orderBy, query works but I need to only update last entry. Can't see what is wrong here..

Answer (score 0):

You are make an `update` statement, where inside it you can't add an order by function in this case.

If you want to order your result you need to make a `select` instead of an update into another query, you can do both, or you need to make a subselect to update only 1 result for example

Comment: Ok, I will try to make a subselect, thanks, I wasn't sure it was possible